# Highstock export .png to variable

Tags: svg, png, export, highcharts

I would like to know if there is a way use the built in export/getSVG function in Highstock to save the exported PNG to a variable in the background instead of prompting the user to download the file.

The thought is for a user to be able to click a button which will export each snapshot to a variable in the background. When done scrolling through the entire chart a subsequent button would create a document containing all the PNG images for a singe download. We can develop everything but the hangup is on saving the PNG image to a variable. We have been able to assign the SVG string to an array we maintain but due to size this would not be the best option for use.

Are there any ways to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this is possible to achieve, see [FAQ](http://docs.highcharts.com/#faq%24export-multiple)

However, there is also one more option - get SVG, and use [canvg](https://code.google.com/p/canvg/) to render into canvas and then to PNG file, as you need.